# What are the other things can be queried in salesforce except object?

Tags: apex

Except standard object or custom setting, what are the other things can be queried.
example : Apex Jobs.

Comment: Is there something in particular that you're trying to query,  but can't? Your question seems rather broad to me. BTW, most everything is considered some kind of object or record related to an object; even if it's not a standard or system object. Even metadata is related to or describes an object of some kind (something that can also be queried by the way).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only other things you can query are custom objects and custom metadata.

`AsyncApexJob` is a standard object by the way.

[This pdf](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/196/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/object_reference.pdf) has a list of standard objects, but not all of these can be queried - take `EmailStatus` as an example. Look for `query()` listed under "Supported Calls"; if the object supports it, you will be able to query for that object's records.